# reload elasticsearch after changing elasticsearch.yml

Tags: elasticsearch

How to make `elasticsearch` apply new configuration? 
I changed one string in file `~ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.yml`:

```
# Disable HTTP completely:
#
http.enabled: false
```

Then tried to reload `elasticsearch`:

```
elasticsearch reload
```

Then tried to restart `elasticsearch`:

```
elasticsearch restart
```

Then checked and see that http requests are still acceptable to elastic search.

So my settings are not applied.

My os is `os X`. ElasticSearch version is `1.2.0`

Answer (score 6):

Strangely or not so, the supposed way to do it is just to stop the service, and start it again :)

I.E. get its pid (running *ps axww | grep elastic*), and then *kill ESpid* ; just be sure to use the TERM signal, to give it a chance to close properly.

Some *nix elasticsearch distros have control scripts wrappers for start/stop , but I don't think OS X does.

And on a side note, you have probably found the [Cluster Update Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html) API, and though it provides quite a few options, regretfully it can't be used to change that particular setting.

HTH

P.S. And yep, in Windows setup the services.msc is the way to do it, but doubt this is helpful for you :)

Comment: `sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch.service; sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service`

Answer (score 0):

When you have installed the current version (7.4 at the time of writing) of Elasticsearch on macOS with Homebrew, you can run:

```sh
brew services restart elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full
```

This will restart Elasticsearch and reload te configuration.

Answer (score -3):

If ElasticSearch is installed on Windows setup then you have to restart ElasticSearch windows service.

Thanks.